# Building cURLpp with vcpkg

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, curlpp

It's my first time including a library  with `vckpg` and Im getting these  warnings when the `curlpp` 's building phase finishes:

- `find_package(unofficial-curlpp CONFIG REQUIRED)`
- `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::curlpp::curlpp)`

I have read the CMake documentation but I still don't know what those refer to. Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: "I'm getting this message when ..." - which message you got?

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself very well. Item listed were the warnings I was getting.

Comment: `find_package(unofficial-curlpp CONFIG REQUIRED)` is just a *command* in `CMakeLists.txt`. A warning message usually contains word "warning" supplied with a **description** of the warning (not just repeating the code). I don't see such warning message in your question post.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. How I said, it was my first time with vcpkg and I thought that I had to use those commands to configure the way the library is built but vcpkg does it automatically. Thanks tho.